# application fails to run when brought over to another pc

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm able to run my application on my development pc but when I copy the whole release folder over to another pc, I click on the exe and it shows "The application failed to initialize properly (0x050002).

Does anyone know what's wrong?

I tried to bring all the related DLLs over but still can't get rid of the error. BTW I'm using Visual C++ 2008.

Comment: Check the VC++ 2008 redist installed on the new machine.

Comment: Maybe you need a proper version of .Net framework?

Answer (score 5):

You must install [Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29) on that computer.

Answer (score 0):

`0x050002` - Probably some component (like MSMQ service) is not installed or not-running, which is required by your application.