# Application not running on a PC with VS 2008 not installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, opencv

I have been working on a project using OpenCV and have made a face detection project.

I would like to know why does an executable created using Visual Studio 2008 not run on another pc and give the following error:
"This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect"

Comment: Probably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788742/application-fails-to-run-when-brought-over-to-another-pc/6788824

Comment: Of course vague error messages are solely found in Windows :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need the Visual C++ Runtime package installed.

Available for download .... [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29)

Comment: Do i need to install this on every pc? or the pc on which i am building the software?

Comment: It is the runtime required on every PC that would use your application if its written in VC++.  Its already installed with VS2008.

Comment: Care to elaborate ..... same error message?  Have you looked at the OpenCV documentation and looked at what dependencies it requires?

Comment: Is that the full extent of the error message, or does it have more information?  That message is often part of a wider message which shows which files have raised the error

Comment: I would follow @m3LinEz advise, and make a release build and try that.  I still think its the VC++ runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package** on the machines you are deploying your application first - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29

> The Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86) installs
>   runtime components of Visual C++ Libraries required to run
>   applications developed with Visual C++ on a computer that does not
>   have Visual C++ 2008 installed.

Another thing to note is you will have to take the binary from **Release** build (not Debug.) The Debug build wouldn't run on the deployment machine even if the VC++ Runtime is installed.

Comment: I'm sorry, is that last bit true??  Its been a long time, but I'm sure I've run debug builds of VC++ applications on a installed system.  Genuine question - it was a long time ago.

Comment: Yeah. I used to distribute Debug-build to some users. It references MSVCR90D.DLL (with 'D' suffixed) which is a debug version of runtime DLLs. So ones who don't have VS installed can't run my app. Having spent some hours resolving this :(

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  I see the OP is off asking questions about making a release build - so he's following your advise it appears.